# minimum moves to be made to get out of convex hull

Tags: algorithms, convex-hull

Given a convex hull in $XY$ plane. and we have $n$ points sitting inside it. In one move we can move all the points to right by $1$ or move all the points to up by $1$. what are the minimum number of moves that are required to get all the points outside the convex hull?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Please credit the original source where you encountered this task.